# Understanding exception handling - Rethrowing exceptions

Tags: java, exception

Consider the below code snippets

In code snippet 1, method m1() has SQLException in throws declaration, but it is actually throwing a reference variable of type `Exception`. I was expecting compiler error here, since `Exception` is not mentioned in the `throws` declaration. But it compiles and prints `Caught successfully`

```
import java.sql.SQLException;
public class Snippet1{
    private static void m() throws SQLException{
        try{
            throw new SQLException();
        } catch(Exception e){
            throw e;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        try{
            m();
        } catch(SQLException e){
            System.out.println("Caught successfully"); //prints "Caught successfully
        }
    }
}
```

Code snippet 2 is almost same as the previous one, except that we assigned `null` to the exception reference variable `e` and then throw it. Now the compiler complains that `Exception` must be caught or declared to be thrown.

```
import java.sql.SQLException;
public class Snippet2{
    private static void m() throws SQLException{
        try{
            throw new SQLException();
        } catch(Exception e){
            e = null;
            throw e;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        try{
            m();
        } catch(SQLException e){
            System.out.println("Caught successfully");
        }
    }
}
```

I do not understand why #1 compiles and #2 doesn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is described in JDK 7 [Rethrowing Exceptions with More Inclusive Type Checking](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/language/catch-multiple.html#rethrow)

> ```java
> public void rethrowException(String exceptionName)
>  throws FirstException, SecondException {
>    try {
>      // ...
>    }
>    catch (Exception e) {
>      throw e;
>    }
>  }
> ```
>
> The Java SE 7 compiler can determine that the exception thrown by the statement throw e must have come from the try block, and the only exceptions thrown by the try block can be `FirstException` and `SecondException`. Even though the exception parameter of the catch clause, e, is type `Exception`, the compiler can determine that it is an instance of either `FirstException` or `SecondException`
>
> This analysis is disabled if the catch parameter is assigned to another value in the catch block. However, if the catch parameter is assigned to another value, you must specify the exception type `Exception` in the throws clause of the method declaration.

Comment: Note that the quoted description is slightly inaccurate.  The compiler can tell that the exception is `FirstException`, `SecondException` ... *or an unchecked exception*.   The point is that `catch (Exception e) { throw e; }` could catch and rethrow (say) an `NullPointerException`.  That's OK ... as far as the JLS is concerned.

Answer (score 0):

There's a rather special voodoo magic rule in the JLS, introduced sometime after JDK6 (I think in JDK7, together with 'multi-catch', where you name multiple exception types, separated with the bar (`|`) character).

If you catch an 'overly broad' exception type, and the variable is `final` or 'effectively final' (never re-assigned), then any `throw t;` statement where `t` is that variable is treated as only representing the exception type(s) that the associated `try` body could actually throw.

In other words:

- In the first snippet, your `Exception e` is effectively final, therefore the rule kicks in.
- Given that the rule kicks in, `throw e;` in snippet 1 is treated as if `e` is actually tightened up to be a disjoint type of all things the try body can throw that are typed as `Exception` or some subtype thereof. In this case, that means: Just `SQLException`.  The method body is declared to `throws SQLException`, thus, `throw e;` is acceptable.
- In the second snippet, `e` is no longer effectively final, as it is re-assigned. Therefore this rule does not kick in, and `throw e;` is simply interpreted as an attempt to throw `Exception`, which isn't legal as the method body doesn't `throws` it and the throw statement is not in a `try` block whose `catch` block deals with `Exception`.

This feature was added to make it simpler to write code that wants to 'peek' at thrown exceptions - they want to do something when an exception occurs, but then they want the exception handling to continue as if they didn't, i.e. that the exception is still thrown, completely unchanged. That's more or less what `finally` is for, except `finally` runs in *all* cases: All exception types, and also runs even if the try body finishes normally or control flows out.

The relevant section of the official documentation is [Java Language Specification §11.2.2](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-11.html#jls-11.2.2).